The department asks us to publish all study protocols of anticipated projects in specific journals to increase the impact factor of the department
Please imagine the following situation: The head of a local department asks his employees to publish all study protocols of upcoming studies in scientific journals. The rationale is as follows: These journals often have an impact factor (e.g. BMC Trials, JMIR Protocols, etc., to name a few). By this step, the head of the departmen wants to increase its global impact factor. While I see some benefit in this step (e.g. research transparency), I fear that this will delay the start of the respective studies. Moreover, I feel that this could be redundant as most studies must be registered at ClinicalTrials.gov or the DRKS (Deutsches Register Klinische Studien) anyway.
When we raised this concern to the head of the deparment, the head argued that this will increase the output of our department. May I ask whether you have heard of similar policies and whether there are any other benefits to registering study protocols? For clarification: I am not talking about pharmaceutical studies but investigator initiated trials. Thank you!

Sounds like an unpleasant situation, sorry to hear you're in it. But, May I ask whether you have heard of similar policies and whether there are any other benefits to registering study protocols? seems like a shopping question and is off-topic for this site.

Maybe most of your studies need to be registered at CT.gov or similar, is that actually true of all your colleagues' work? Not all medical research, even in humans, is required to be registered or considered a clinical trial.

I fail to see how this is a shopping question (CC @RichardErickson) as nothing is shopped for. However, you are asking two different questions and one of them is a survey, to which every answer is equally valid. I can imagine quite a few relevant questions about this situation, e.g., whether the department can enforce this, whom to complain to, etc., but for these you need to state some clear goals you want to achieve and probably also give us some background information.

This is called "juking the stats" (it is what happens in corrupt academic departments)
So, your Head of Department wants you to "juke that stats" to improve the quantitative research metrics of his Department: "making robberies into larcenies, making rapes disappear; you juke the stats and majors become colonels."
It is up to you whether you want to participate in this charade, or just do good research and let the citations and impact factors fall where they may.  If it is genuinely useful to give advanced publication of your study protocols then you may go ahead and do this, but it sounds like this is not useful and would be done solely as a way of artificially inflating citation metrics and other research metrics.  Alternatively, you may exercise control over your own research program and output, pre-register your studies on standard platforms, and then do good research and publish your papers after you have completed your studies.  Take the flak from your Head of Department if needed, and keep your eye out for opportunities to transfer to another institution.
As to your specific question, I have never heard of any policy at any research institution that instructs academics what papers they must publish.  That is something that would interfere with academic freedom and override the professional discretion of academics who have specialist knowledge in their fields.  At most, something like this might be a localised practice that is "encouraged" by senior people in the institution, sometimes in a manner that reminds us of a well-known police drama.  It could also hamper academic promotion if the Head of Department reacts adversely to your intransigence, but again, that is a feature of corrupt academic departments.  Best to just do good work, maintain respect for yourself and your profession, and let the research metrics fall where they may.
